# Is it has turned out or turned out?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

I've been wondering about which tense I should use in the following phrase:

> I am grateful that the episode **turned** out the way it **has**

or

> I am grateful that the episode **turned** out the way it **was**

or

> I am grateful that the episode **has turned** out the way it **has**

I'm leaning more to the last option as I'm not specifying a time period, and I just want to express my opinion/feelings about the episode of my favorite show.

Comment: The way it did.

Comment: You can use  either _turned out the way it did_ or _has turned out the way it has_.

Comment: Yeah, in the U.S., you'd say "turned out the way it did," but I have to admit, when I read "turned out the way it has," it didn't immediately sound wrong to me, so that one might be in the category of close enough.

Answer (score 1):

"I am grateful that the episode turned out the way it was" is not grammatically wrong, but the commonly used phrasing of this would be

"I am grateful that the episode turned out the way it *did*"